# Rotate rectangle and move it in sin wave - Help using graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d, rotatetransform

Hi!

I have the code below using previous Stackoverflow posts.

I want to just rotate the rectangle by some angle and make it move in sin wave.

This code rotates the whole sin wave too.

I understand why it is happening , but I don't know how to achieve my intention.

please help!!!

Thanks a lot for taking time.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Withrotation {

    public static int i = 1;
    public static Ticker t;
    public static Repainter r;
    public static int newx, newy;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Wavy!");
        final WavyPanel wp = new WavyPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(wp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t = new Ticker(wp);
        r = new Repainter(wp);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        final Timer tickTimer = new Timer();
        final Timer paintTimer = new Timer();
        paintTimer.schedule(r, 1000, 50);
        tickTimer.schedule(t, 1000, 10);
    }

    private static class WavyPanel extends JPanel {

        private final Dimension size = new Dimension(640, 480);
        private int amplitude = 50;
        private int frequency = 5;
        private double x1 = 0;
        private double y1 = 500;
        private int yBase = 0;

        WavyPanel() {
            super(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
            final Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            AffineTransform old = g2.getTransform();
            g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(-30));

            g2.clearRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.fillRect((int) x1, (int) y1, 20, 80);
            g2.setTransform(old);


        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void tick() {
            x1 = x1 + 1;
            final int waveLength = size.width / frequency;
            yBase = (++yBase) % waveLength;
            final double normalized = (double) yBase / (double) waveLength;
            final double radians = normalized * Math.PI * 2;
            final double sine = Math.sin(radians);
            y1 = (int) (sine * amplitude);




        }
    }

    private static class Ticker extends TimerTask {

        private final WavyPanel panel;

        Ticker(final WavyPanel panel) {

            this.panel = panel;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            panel.tick();
        }
    }

    private static class Repainter extends TimerTask {

        private final WavyPanel panel;

        Repainter(final WavyPanel panel) {

            this.panel = panel;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            panel.repaint();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

+1 for SSCCE

1) Dont forget to have call to `super.paintComponent();` as first statement in your overridden `paintComponent(..)` method.

2) Swing UI should be created on [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and used in conjunction with [Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

3) Java variable naming convention for classes is uppercase letter for each new word i.e `WithRotation`.

4) No need for `frame.getContentPane.add(..)` simply use `add(..)` as all calls are forwarded to its *contentPane*.

Here is the example I made (basically your code with above fixes implemented), which only rotates the rectangle which follows the graph and not the whole graphics object using [`AffineTransform#createTransformedShape()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape%28java.awt.Shape%29):

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class WithRotation {

    private JFrame frame;
    private WavyPanel wp;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new WithRotation();
            }
        });
    }

    public WithRotation() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        frame = new JFrame("Wavy!");
        wp = new WavyPanel();
        frame.add(wp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        createAndStartTimers();
    }

    private void createAndStartTimers() {
        new Timer(50, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                wp.repaint();
            }
        }).start();
        new Timer(10, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

                wp.tick();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    class WavyPanel extends JPanel {

        private final Dimension size = new Dimension(640, 480);
        private int amplitude = 50;
        private int frequency = 5;
        private double x1 = 0;
        private double y1 = 500;
        private int yBase = 0;

        WavyPanel() {
            super(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

            g2.clearRect(0, 0, this.getSize().width, this.getSize().height);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle((int) x1, (int) y1, 20, 80);

            AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
            transform.rotate(Math.toRadians(-30), rect.getX() + rect.width / 2, rect.getY() + rect.height / 2);

            Shape transformed = transform.createTransformedShape(rect);
            g2.fill(transformed);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
            return size;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
            return size;
        }

        public void tick() {
            x1 = x1 + 1;
            final int waveLength = size.width / frequency;
            yBase = (++yBase) % waveLength;
            final double normalized = (double) yBase / (double) waveLength;
            final double radians = normalized * Math.PI * 2;
            final double sine = Math.sin(radians);
            y1 = (int) (sine * amplitude);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that is the output I usually get,this code makes the output just perfect!But what I need is that rectangle to rotate by say some angle and still move in the same Sin Wave.When I use rotate,The whole sin wave is also rotated,but I just want the rectangle to rotate.Hope I am clear.Thanks for the reply.

Comment: AWESOME!!!!!! You made my day! ..createTransformed shape is the key! Thanks a lot. You guys are wonderful !