# How to rotate an ImageIcon() with actionPerformed()?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, java-2d

I am having difficulties rotating an imageicon by using the arrow keys.

I currently have the following as my code

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class startGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener
{
Timer time = new Timer(5,this);
int x=0,y=0,velX = 0,velY=0;
Image car1;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    startGame game = new startGame();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("NEED FOR SPEED");
    frame.setSize(800,800);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(game);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D) g;
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("car1.jpg");
    car1=ii.getImage();
    ga.drawImage(car1, x, y, null);
    time.start();
}

public startGame()
{
    time.start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    repaint();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    if(x<0)
    {
        velX=0;
        x=0;
    }
    if(y<0)
    {
        velY=0;
        y=0;
    }
    if(x>800)
    {
        velX=0;
        x=800;
    }
    if(y>800)
    {
        velY=0;
        y=800;
    }
    x = x + velX;
    y = y + velY;
    repaint();
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    velX=0;
    velY=0;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    int c = e.getKeyCode();

    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
    {
        velX = -1;
        velY = 0;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
    {
        velX = 0;
        velY = -1;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
    {
        velX = 1;
        velY = 0;
    }
    if(c == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
    {
        velX = 0;
        velY = 1;
    }
}
}
```

To rotate the image I have tried the following in the paint component method

```
ga.rotate(Math.toRadians(45),26,26);
```

and

```
ga.rotate(Math.toRadians(360));
```

but all it does is rotate the paint component and not the image.

What I am looking for is how can I rotate the image "car1" only, so that when VK_RIGHT OR VK_LEFT is pressed the image rotates to the desired direction, respectively. Also when VK_UP or VK_DOWN are pressed the image rotates to that direction, respectively.

And sorry for the lengthy code, but all was necessary. As the question involves multiple methods.

Thank you forum.

Comment: 1) `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D) g;
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("car1.jpg");
    ..`  The image should be read by now and stored as a class attribute. 2) `ga.drawImage(car1, x, y, null);` should be `ga.drawImage(car1, x, y, this);`

Comment: So, if the image is stored as a class attribute, is there a way to rotate it? Or does it stay as is.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12824684/change-the-angle-position-of-a-drawing-with-a-algorithm-in-java/12826882#12826882) might help

Comment: 1) *"if the image is stored as a class attribute, is there a way to rotate it?"*  Sure there is.  Rotate the graphics context using any number of methods, or paint it to a 2nd image already rotated (less efficient). 2) @MadProgrammer  Nice example, as always. :)

Comment: As said by @AndrewThompson you can rotate the Graphics object by overriding paintComponent. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519449/rotate-rectangle-and-move-it-in-sin-wave-help-using-graphics2d/13519588#13519588) is an example using a simple rectangle and AffineTransform sure it can be evolved for your needs. +1 to mad comment and example (lol sorry my last comment linked mads answer :O)

Answer (score 4):

- Please dont use `KeyListener`/`KeyAdapter` thats for AWT. Rather use [`KeyBinding`s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for Swing components (with no exceptions IMO).
- Unless another class should have access to the `KeyListener` `keyPressed` etc methods (though you shouldn't use this) or `actionPerformed` than there is no need for the class to implement it, rather create an instance to work with within the class.
- Also rather override `getPreferredSize` of `JPanel` so you can call `pack()` on `JFrame` rather than `setSize()` which is bad practice. Also never set `JFrame` visible before all components have been added
- Also I see you start your timer in 2 places (the constructor and `paintComponent`), rather just start it in the constructor and it will remain running unless you called `Timer#setRepeats(false)`.
- I see no use for `ImageIcon` , rather just simply used a `BufferedImage`
- Do not load images or do lenghty operations etc in `paintComponent(..)` besides pure drawing

As per above here is your code with fixes:

NB: I used my own `KeyBinding` class just to make things a bit easier.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Transparency;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Nfs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Need for Speed");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new startGame());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class startGame extends JPanel {

    private int x = 0, y = 0, velX = 0, velY = 0, width = 800, height = 600;
    private BufferedImage transformedImage;
    private Timer time = new Timer(5, new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (x < 0) {
                velX = 0;
                x = 0;
            }
            if (y < 0) {
                velY = 0;
                y = 0;
            }
            if (x > width) {
                velX = 0;
                x = width;
            }
            if (y > height) {
                velY = 0;
                y = height;
            }
            x = x + velX;
            y = y + velY;
            repaint();
        }
    });

    public startGame() {

        transformedImage = createTransformedImage(createCar(), 45);

        addKeyBindings();
        time.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D) g;

        ga.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        ga.drawImage(transformedImage, x, y, null);
    }
    //Simply used for testing (to simulate sprites) 

    public static BufferedImage createCar() {
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        g2.dispose();
        return img;
    }

    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156518/rotate-an-image-in-java
    public static BufferedImage createTransformedImage(BufferedImage image, double angle) {
        double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
        int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
        int neww = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin), newh = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);
        BufferedImage result = new BufferedImage(neww, newh, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
        Graphics2D g2d = result.createGraphics();
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.translate((neww - w) / 2, (newh - h) / 2);
        g2d.rotate(angle, w / 2, h / 2);
        g2d.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
        g2d.dispose();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, height);
    }

    private void addKeyBindings() {
        AbstractAction onReleaseAction = new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                velX = 0;
                velY = 0;
            }
        };

        //we are adding multiple keybindigs with same focus map etc to same component so we intitae an instance of class rate than use static methods
        KeyBinding kb = new KeyBinding(this, KeyBinding.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

        kb.addKeyBindingOnPressAndRelease(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                velX = 0;
                velY = 1;
            }
        }, "down pressed", onReleaseAction, "down released");

        kb.addKeyBindingOnPressAndRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                velX = 0;
                velY = -1;
            }
        }, "up pressed", onReleaseAction, "up released");

        kb.addKeyBindingOnPressAndRelease(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                velX = -1;
                velY = 0;
            }
        }, "left pressed", onReleaseAction, "left released");
        kb.addKeyBindingOnPressAndRelease(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                velX = 1;
                velY = 0;
            }
        }, "right pressed", onReleaseAction, "right released");
    }
}

class KeyBinding {

    private final JComponent container;
    private final int inputMap;
    public static final int WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW,
            WHEN_FOCUSED = JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED,
            WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT = JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT;

    public KeyBinding(JComponent container, int inputMap) {
        this.container = container;
        this.inputMap = inputMap;
    }

    public void addKeyBinding(int key, boolean onRelease, AbstractAction keybindingAction, String description) {
        putKeyBinding(container, inputMap, key, onRelease, keybindingAction, description);
    }

    public void addKeyBindingOnPress(int key, AbstractAction keybindingAction, String description) {
        putKeyBinding(container, inputMap, key, false, keybindingAction, description);
    }

    public void addKeyBindingOnRelease(int key, AbstractAction keybindingAction, String description) {
        putKeyBinding(container, inputMap, key, true, keybindingAction, description);
    }

    public void addKeyBindingOnPressAndRelease(int key, AbstractAction onPressAction, String onPressDesc, AbstractAction onReleaseAction, String onReleaseDesc) {
        putKeyBinding(container, inputMap, key, false, onPressAction, onPressDesc);
        putKeyBinding(container, inputMap, key, true, onReleaseAction, onReleaseDesc);
    }

    public static void putKeyBinding(JComponent container, int inputMap, int key, boolean onRelease, AbstractAction keybindingAction, String description) {
        container.getInputMap(inputMap).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key, 0, onRelease), description);
        container.getActionMap().put(description, keybindingAction);
    }

    public static void putKeyBindingOnPress(JComponent container, int inputMap, int key, AbstractAction keybindingAction, String description) {
        container.getInputMap(inputMap).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key, 0, false), description);
        container.getActionMap().put(description, keybindingAction);
    }

    public static void putKeyBindingOnRelease(JComponent container, int inputMap, int key, AbstractAction keybindingAction, String description) {
        container.getInputMap(inputMap).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key, 0, true), description);
        container.getActionMap().put(description, keybindingAction);
    }

    public static void putKeyBindingOnPressAndRelease(JComponent container, int inputMap, int key, AbstractAction onPressAction, String onPressDesc, AbstractAction onReleaseAction, String onReleaseDesc) {
        putKeyBinding(container, inputMap, key, false, onPressAction, onPressDesc);
        putKeyBinding(container, inputMap, key, true, onReleaseAction, onReleaseDesc);
    }
}
```

**References:**

- [Rotate an image in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156518/rotate-an-image-in-java)

Comment: +1 for `AffineTransformOp `; see also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3420651/230513).

Comment: @DharavPatel please see mu update. +1 joeyrohan and trashgod. Thank you.